# Using c_str() on String for IPAddress with NTPClient provides wrong values

Tags: ethernet, string, esp32, tcpip, c-string

### Libraries

- [NTPClient](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/NTPClient)

### Board

Olimex ESP32-POE board

### Behaviour

I have written a code that connects the board to a local NTP Server (which is an embedded board). I tried assigning the IP Address of the above NTP Server using `IPAddress` and then convert it to `c_str()` to pass into the `NTPClient` constructor as follows:

```cpp
 WiFiUDP ntpUDP; // udp socket object for NTP

 IPAddress NTPServer(192.168.3.11); // Local NTP Server IP Address

 NTPClient timeClient(ntpUDP, NTPServer.toString().c_str(), 0, 60000);
```

The reason for this is because the `NTPClient` class uses `const char*` for the IP Address of the NTP Server.

The values that are obtained once the code is flashed on the board are wrong because the timestamps are have the year `2106`.

On the contrary, when I use

```cpp
 NTPClient timeClient(ntpUDP, "192.168.3.11", 0, 60000);
```

and run the code on the board, this provides me perfect values of UTC time.

Why is there some discrepancy here?

## Code

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#include <ETH.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <NTPClient.h>
#include <RTClib.h>

WiFiUDP ntpUDP;
/* IP CONF for NODE */
///////// >>>> MODIFY Values Here <<<< ////////
const IPAddress node_static_ip(192, 168, 3, 101);
const IPAddress default_gateway(192, 168, 3, 250);
const IPAddress subnet_mask(255, 255, 255, 0);
const IPAddress dns_add(192, 168, 3, 250);
const IPAddress NTPServer(192, 168, 3, 11);

NTPClient timeClient(ntpUDP, "192.168.3.11", 0, 60000); // This works
NTPClient timeClient(ntpUDP, NTPServer.toString().c_str(), 0, 60000); // This won't (provides timestamps of 2106)

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Wire.begin(I2C_SDA, I2C_SCL);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  ETH.begin();
  ETH.config(node_static_ip, default_gateway, subnet_mask, dns_add);
  delay(1000);
  if (!rtc.begin()) {
    Serial.println("No RTC");
  }
  timeClient.begin();

}
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  timeClient.update();
  Serial.println(timeClient.getEpochTime());
  DateTime now_time(timeClient.getEpochTime());
  Serial.print(now_time.year(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(now_time.month(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(now_time.day(), DEC);
    Serial.print(now_time.hour(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(now_time.minute(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(now_time.second(), DEC);
Serial.println();

  delay(2000);

}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `toString().c_str()`, not `toString.c_str()`?

Comment: Sorry Typo! I meant the latter.

Comment: I thought so, since the former doesn't compile.  A simple test of printing to serial works fine. I suggest adding that into your program to make sure it's actually converting it wrong and not something else.  `Serial.println(NTPServer.toString().c_str());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The String object created as return from IPAddress.toString() as parameter to constructor of NtpClient is temporary. It contains the char array returned by c_str(). NTPClient doesn't copy the string, only stores a reference to it. And the referenced string (char array) doesn't exist at the time the NTPClient wants to use it.

```
class TestClass {
public:
  TestClass(const char* _ip) : ip(_ip) { }

  void test() {
    Serial.println("--");
    Serial.println(ip);
    Serial.println("--");
  }

private:
  const char* ip;
};


//String s("abc");
//TestClass Test(s.c_str()); <- this works

TestClass Test(String("abc").c_str()); // <- this can't work

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Test.test();
}
```